# How to create text overlay on a bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just wondering if someone can show me the best way to show some text over a panel in jquery/javascript using some sort of overlay.

I want to disable everything in the panel and then show a big 'canceled' centered right in the middle.

Right now I have just a regular bootstrap panel like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sawq08d/8/)

Here is some of the code I have so far

```js
$(".panel").addClass('.disabledbutton');
```

```css
.disabledbutton {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Panel title
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean a pop up text saying 'cancelled'?

Comment: no, no popup. Just disabling everything in the panel and then showing a big fat 'cancelled' right in the center of the panel or even just the panel body. Would this be easily done in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the easiest way to do this would be, to put another div inside your panel with cancelled written in it and then hide it by default and then show it when you want it to have cancelled written there so

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <p>Panel content</p>
   <div class="panel-body_cancelled">
       <h1>CANCELLED</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

then in your CSS

```
.panel-body_cancelled{
    display: none;
}

.panel-body_cancelled_active{
    display: block;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

then in your jQuery say you want to activate the cancelled div with a click event

```
$('.yourbutton').click(function(){
    $(.panel-body_cancelled).toggleClass('panel-body_cancelled_active');
})
```